# Firebase inapp messaging showing only one time even after setting per day one time option as frequency limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have created one campaign by showing a inapp messaging popup to user while they do particular event. While scheduling the campaign i have set frequency limit as per day one time as option for frequency limit. But it shows only one time to user, it is not showing on the next day. 
I saw Firebase inapp messaging is beta version, but not sure which all functionalities will work or not properly. Any ideas or comments on this?

Comment: I m facing the same issue..have you found any solution?

Comment: FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessagesSuppressed(false); 

Can you check the above code.

Comment: My issue is resolved by importing google-json file again